# Make WPF TextBox stretch to available space and not grow with Text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I make the `TextBox` stretch until the button with the three dots, but not cover it when somebody enters a lot of text?

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.Bar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar.Properties"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <DockPanel>
        <Label Name="lblFileName" Content="File"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="txbFileName"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btnOpenFileDialog" Content="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
      </DockPanel>
      <UniformGrid>
        <Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnBar" Content="Bar"></Button>
      </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

What it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stretch your TextBox set `LastChildFill="true"` on DockPanel and add TextBox in the end.

Btw. If you're using DockPanel you can use `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` instead of `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label Name="lblFileName" Content="File"></Label>
            <Button Name="btnOpenFileDialog" Content="..." DockPanel.Dock="Right"></Button>
            <TextBox Name="txbFileName"></TextBox>
        </DockPanel>
        <UniformGrid>
            <Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo"></Button>
            <Button Name="btnBar" Content="Bar"></Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: A nice advantage of this approach is also that if you stretch your main window (assuming you want that to be possible) the TextBox will automatically accommodate itself to that new size.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the MaxWidth of the TextBox to the width of the space you want to stay inside. This will take a bit of addition and subtraction, and maybe a bit of estimation, but it will work. Having it actually stretch seems a bit odd, but if you really want that in particular, then an example setting might be:

```
<TextBox Name="txbFileName" MaxWidth=300*></TextBox>
```